# sql query to find Which country has the maximum number of suppliers and customers

Tags: sql

**Customer Table columns:**

CustomerID  CompanyName ContactName ContactTitle    Address City    Region  PostalCode  Country Phone   Fax

**Supplier table Columns:**

SupplierID  CompanyName ContactName ContactTitle    Address City    Region  PostalCode  Country Phone   Fax HomePage

*from these table how we find " Which country has the maximum number of suppliers and customers...?"
 i need query for the above problem....?
 Pls answer me any one....!*

Comment: Yes i have tried but am not able to get accurate answer...

Comment: Yes, you may have tried, but _what_ have you tried? Show us some effort, we appreciate that on SO.

Comment: Also - is this MySQL? Or MSSQL? What does C# and VB have to do with this question? Don't tag frivolously.

Answer (score 2):

To get the maximum times a single country is included *in both tables* as a single value, union them, then group them:

```
 select top 1 x.Country
 from (
   select Country from Customer
   union all
   select Country from Supplier) x
 group by x.Country
 order by count(1) desc
```

---

edit: alternatively, you could group the two tables separately, then full-outer-join them together, and add matching terms (remembering to handle the `null`s from countries that are in only one of the two lists):

```
select top 1 ISNULL(x.Country, y.Country) as [Country]
from (
  select Country, COUNT(1) as [Count] from Customers
  group by Country) x
full outer join (
  select Country, COUNT(1) as [Count] from Suppliers
  group by Country) y
on x.Country = y.Country
order by ISNULL(x.[Count], 0) + ISNULL(y.[Count], 0) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL server syntax

maximum number of customers

```
select Country from (
(with cte as (select Country,COUNT(*) cnt
from Customer
group by Country)
select Country,Rank() over (order by cnt desc) row_num from cte)a
where a.row_num=1
```

maximum number of suppliers

```
select Country from (
(with cte as (select Country,COUNT(*) cnt
from suppliers
group by Country)
select Country,Rank() over (order by cnt desc) row_num from cte)a
where a.row_num=1
```

Comment: Using a CTE and RANK will get the same result, but wouldn't a TOP 1 be far simpler for everyone (and the optimizer)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.country AS MaxCustomers, b.country AS MaxSuppliers
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 country
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY country
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 country
    FROM suppliers
    GROUP BY country
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) b
```

Should output something like:

```
MaxCustomers    |    MaxSuppliers
---------------------------------
USA             |    Japan
```

Comment: i got this but my problem is finding a country that has highest no. of customers and supplier...